# The response parameter in QueueClient.message_decode_policy.decode function

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage

Here is my Python script. The purpose is to read message content from an Azure Storage Queue.

```
my_queue_client=QueueClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connection_string, queue_name="queue1")
my_queue_client.message_decode_policy=BinaryBase64DecodePolicy()
my_msgs = my_queue_client.receive_messages()
for message in my_msgs:
    my_content=my_queue_client.message_decode_policy.decode(message.content, response)
```

I could not figure out what the response parameter should be.
Here is [decode function documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-queue/azure.storage.queue.binarybase64decodepolicy?view=azure-python#azure-storage-queue-binarybase64decodepolicy-decode)

Thank you.

Comment: The error message showed that the "response" parameter is "http_reponse". But I still do not understand why this is needed for a base64 decode function.

Comment: Can you confirm if you want the output in [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/Gzz6ZJv.png) format? OR base64 decoded format?

Comment: Without decoding, the message variable returned scrambled text. So I tried to decode it somehow. What I do not understand is why a response parameter is needed and what object this response parameter is.

Comment: Does this help https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/9995?